# If $\gcd(a,3)=1$, then $a^3\equiv \pm 1\pmod 9$

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $\gcd(a,3)=1$, then $a^3\equiv \pm 1\pmod 9$
(which is equivalent to $9 \mid a^3\pm 1$, I guess). Also, show that the equation $3x^2+5=2y^3$ will have no solutions.

Comment: $\gcd(a,3)=1\implies \gcd(a,9)=1$. And $\phi(9)=6$, which allows a quick proof, or at worst we're only talking about calculating $6$ values of $a^3 \bmod 9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\:gcd\left(a,3\right)=1$ it follows $a = 3k \pm 1$ so $a^3=9m \pm 1$

Regarding $3x^2+5=2y^3$ we can see $\:gcd\left(y,3\right)=1$.

Applying mod 9 we get $3x^2 + 5 = \pm 2 \mod 9 \tag 1$ equivalent $3x^2=6 \mod 9 \tag 2$ or $3x^2=2 \mod 9 \tag 3$

(2) and (3) have no solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $a=3k\pm 1$ for some $k$. Therefore, $a^3=27k^3\pm 27k^2+9k\pm 1$.

Also, from $3(x^2+1)=2(y^3-1)$ we have that $3|y^3-1$ so $y=3t+1$ for some t. But then we also have $9|y^3-1$ and from here: $3|x^2+1$. This means that $x^2=2\mod 3$, which doesn't hold.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks, I've edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ca+3d=1$ implies that $c^3a^3=1+9e$, now find numbers invertible in $Z/9$.

Comment: $(1-3d)^3\neq 1+9d$.

Comment: You meant $(1-3d)^3=1+9e$ for some $e\in\mathbb Z$. It follows from the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\varphi(9)=6$, the group $\mathbb{Z}/(9\mathbb{Z})^*$ has exactly $6$ elements (namely $1,2,4,5,7,8$) and the range of the map $x\mapsto x^3$ has cardinality $\frac{6}{3}=2$. We may finish by noticing that $\pm 1$ are always cubic residues.